# In bootstrap v4 latest, is there a benefit on using col class name only on div rather than any other type of doms? and vise versa?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

For example, could we just use on any doms we want to, no limit? or there is a best practice how it should be used? Because I see some teammate start using `span` or `h1` with class name of `col-md-1` or such and there is really no written limit on how we should use it on bootstrap doc.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "yes" you could. As far as best practice is concerned it is up to you and the standards you have in place. View snippet below. I have added the col class to a `h1` tag

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h1 class="col">
      1 of 2
    </h1>
    <h1 class="col">
      2 of 2
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      2 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      3 of 3
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h1>1 of 4</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <h1>2 of 4</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would suggest however that you stick with the div tags as they are meant to be wrappers and you can add inside the other tags needed. See above snippet. I will point out that the `h1` tags with class of col on them act just like the last "row" where the `div` tags have the class applied to them

Comment: Let me also point out. Here is the [official documentation from Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/) regarding the "grid system"

Comment: I agree. Looking at the styles applied via `.col` I don't see any reason why not other than it just feels gross. A flex item is neither `block`, `inline-block` nor `inline`. It really acts like a new display type, so applying to an different display types shouldn't matter.

Comment: well my teammate's justification is that, it produce better performance because since we apply the `col-x` directly onto the actual dom (i.e. h1) we trying to make responsive instead of put it inside a div and make the h1 an internal dom has 100% width. I can't verify the performance part, but lesser dom depth certain better for page load that is no doubt.

Comment: @Ezeewei That could be the case. I am unaware of any performance boosts, but if it does help with performance that is really good to know

Answer (score 1):

`row` and `col` classes are supposed to be containers to form layout. But I think sometimes might be useful to apply those classes not just to divs, but to more semantically correct elements. For example if you have a list of items then you can do like this:

```
<ul class="row">
    <li class="col">
        // Actual stuff here
    </li>
    .....
</ul>
```

It allows to avoid unnecessary `div` tags and keep html semantically correct.